# Var Interpolation inside the Locals in Jade Template

Tags: pug

I would need the date to be reflected in the paragraph. Is there a way to do it jade?

```
var locals = {
  date: '23-4-2016',
  recipient: {
    name: "John Doe",
  },
  paragraph: 'some text #{locals.date}  some text',
  borrower: "John Doe"
};
```

---

### template.pug

```
p=paragraph
```

### output

some text #{locals.date}  some text

### What I actually want

some text 23-4-2016 some text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User other variable for `some text` **first** and `some text` **last**, like this:

```
-var date = '23-04-2016';
-var firstText = 'some text first ';
-var lastText = ' some text last';
```

Then declare your variable use variables before with `+` operator:

```
-var paragraph = firstText + date + lastText;
```

Then print in a view with `p= paragraph`, result is:

`some text first 23-04-2016 some text last`

I'm using jade template, but I think pug is the same.

Comment: Thanks Makes sense. What i actually did is, I compiled the paragraph(s) with data and then passed them in to the actual template which solved my actual problem. I didn't want to use 'var', you solution works though.

Comment: That sound is good, I declare variable because maybe your message it not fixed, you can type fixed text for `firstText` and `lastText` in `-var paragraph` if it's not change.